# how do I access information from specific files in specific folders with os.walk

Tags: python

This question expands on my previous question, I have another problem with the code. I tried posting this question in an edited version of my last question, but it went unnoticed. So here I go again:

ADDED PROBLEM:

I got the answer to my first question, now I have another. In the directories under the root there are many sub-directories. I want to access information from only one sub-directory that has the same name in all directories. This is what I tried:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/rootPath/"):
  for dname in dirs:
    #print dname, type(dname)
    allPIs = []
    allDirs = []
    if dname.endswith('code_output'):  #I only want to access information from one file in sub-directories with this name
      ofh = open("sumPIs.txt", 'w')
      ofh.write("path\tPIs_mean\n")
      for fname in files: #Here i want to be in the code_output sub-directory
        print fname #here I only want to see files in the sub-directory with the 'code_output' end of a name, but I get all files in the directory AND sub-directory
        if fname.endswith('sumAll.txt'):
          PIs = []
          with open(os.path.join(root,fname), 'r') as fh_in:
            for line in fh_in:
              line = line.rstrip()
              line = line.split('\t')
              PIs.append(int(line[2]))
          PIs_mean = numpy.mean(PIs)
          allPIs.append(PIs_mean)
          allDirs.append(filePath)
```

Why does this loop over ALL files in the directory and not only the sub-directory with the name ending 'code_output'?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a 100% sure I get your question. I assume that you want to operate on all files that end with the string `sumAll.txt` in each `code_output` subdirectory.

If that is the case then you can simply get rid of the second for loop:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/rootPath/"):
  if root.endswith('code_output'):
    allPIs = []
    allDirs = []
    # Create sumPIs.txt in /rootPath/.../code_output
    ofh = open("sumPIs.txt", 'w')
    ofh.write("path\tPIs_mean\n")
    # Iterate over all files in /rootPath/.../code_output
    for fname in files:
      print fname
      if fname.endswith('sumAll.txt'):
        PIs = []
        with open(os.path.join(root, fname), 'r') as fh_in:
          for line in fh_in:
            line = line.rstrip()
            line = line.split('\t')
            PIs.append(int(line[2]))
        PIs_mean = numpy.mean(PIs)
        allPIs.append(PIs_mean)
        allDirs.append(filePath)
```